# Why does my boolean return 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, boolean, logical-operators, reduce

I'm working through Eloquent Javascript and there's an exercise to make an `every` function, which takes an array and a function and returns true or false depending on what all the items in the array return after going through the function.

I'm confused because when I do console.log() within the function, I get the boolean twice...but when I do console.log(every(arr, func)), I get `undefined`.

```
var every = function(arr, req){
    arr.map(function(item){
        return req(item);
    }).reduce(
        function(total, num){

            // this returns: true
            //               true
            console.log(total && num);

            return total && num;
    });


}

// This returns undefined
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
```

So why do I get `true` twice inside my function, and why do I get undefined?

I'm using node as a console.

Comment: you never returned anything from `every`, so `console.log(every(...))` will always be undefined.

Comment: The missing `return` aside, you *really* should just use `arr.every(req)`, and if you go for `reduce` nonetheless you should *always* pass an initial accumulator value to cover empty arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a return statement to your outermost function, like this:

```
var every = function(arr, req){
    return arr.map(function(item){
        return req(item);
    }).reduce(
        function(total, num){ 
            return total && num;
    });
}

// This returns true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
```

EDIT: Fixed return value, thanks @Kevin B

Comment: @KevinB absolutely, my bad.